# Orbeon Form Builder - Session Issue

Tags: java, tomcat, orbeon

I have been facing an  issue in the orbeon form builder. It asks me often to reload the page. How many requests would it handle at a time?. Is there any specific tomcat configuration to handle multiple requests?. There seems to be a memory issue. I have added the configuration in the TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh file. I have also attached the screen shot of the error dialogue and the tomcat console error message. Please guide me on this to resolve issues.

Tomcat Configuration

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms1024m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx4096m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

ORBEON_MEMORY_OPTS="-Xms300m -Xmx1000m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -verbosegc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
ORBEON_DEBUG_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=61155,suspend=n,server=y"
export JAVA_OPTS="$ORBEON_MEMORY_OPTS -server"
```

Error Dialogue

[image]

Tomcat Console Error
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you get such a dialog, one of two things might have happened: either there was a JavaScript error that happened on the browser, or there was an error the server. When the former happens, the dialog includes some more information about the error, which doesn't seem to be showing here. So you're most likely in the latter case: an error happened on the server.

To see what it is, you need to look at the `orbeon.log`. It is in `../logs/orbeon.log` relative to the directory where you start Tomcat, which if you start it in `bin` will point to Tomcat's `logs` directory. Check the `orbeon.log` just after you get such an error, and see if you can find an exception at the bottom of the file.

(If looking at the log file doesn't help, feel free to post it somewhere, e.g. on https://gist.github.com/, update your question to include a link to the file, and post a comment here, so I'm notified do you did so.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Still i have not got the solution look for: Please verify this and let me know how to resolve multiple access issue. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560041/form-builder-multiple-user-access-issue

Comment: I've answered your other question, but there too, the next step would be to analyze the `orbeon.log`. And if you can't figure out what the problem is by looking at it, feel free to send it to us (e.g. uploading it on https://gist.github.com/), and we'll do our best to help.