# Form Builder - Multiple User Access Issue

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, orbeon

I am facing an issue with form builder while it is accessed by more than one user at a time. There is no issue if only one member accesses it. I am getting the following error dialogue often.

[image]
​

The following is the tomcat console output. I am using tomcat 6.0.37.

[image]

I have explored the http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/context-and-session-listeners page. It says that "The Orbeon Forms Servlet Context Listener allows configuring one processor to be called when the Servlet context is initialized, and one to be called when the Servlet context is destroyed." We are using orbeon 4.5.30 Community Edition. Is it an issue with Community Edition or will it occur in Professional Edition too? Please guide me on this to configure the Form Builder to be accessed by multiple user at time.

Answer (score 0):

If due to a bug in the product, I doubt this is a CE-specific issue. As for the warning you point to in the screenshot, this isn't something to be overly worried about. There is a long standing [issue for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/182), this is something that should be cleaned up, but in practice it poses no problem.

However, I don't remember ever seeing an issue where having just multiple users access the system causes that type of issue. As in my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614397/5295) where you describe a similar symptom, I'd really recommend you look at the `orbeon.log`. In general the root cause for the issue can be found there. And again, if you can't quite figure out what the issue is based on what you have in `orbeon.log`, feel free to post that file somewhere, link to it in a comment, and we'll try to see if we can find something for you.